# Group sorting algorithm using max hash and quantity of accounts

Tags: contract-development

Would it be possible to design an algorithm for pseudo-randomly sorting accounts into groups, by using the maximum number of accounts on Ethereum, the max value of a 256-bit number, `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, 
then treat the hash of an account as a large random number.

Something similar to the algorithm

```
userGroup[msg.sender] = uint(userHash[msg.sender]) / (uint(maxHash) / numGroups()) + 1;
```

*g* is group index, *n* is account hash, *k* is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, *p* is number of groups.

```
g = n / (k / p) + 1
```

How large does the quantity of *n* have to be for a similar algorithm to work ? What is the lower-bound for quantity of *n* when it becomes unusable ?

What would be an example of a similar algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is just to pseudo-randomly assigning account to buckets, than you can simply use `uint(address) % n` to distribute among buckets numbered `0` to `n-1` (see also: [Non-cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions)). If you have an additional requirement for this assignment to be unpredictable, this becomes much more complicated due to the lack of true randomness on the blockchain.

> How large does the quantity of n have to be for a similar algorithm to
>   work ? What is the lower-bound for quantity of n when it becomes
>   unusable ?

It's not entirely clear, what do you mean by "work" / "usable". What requirements do you have?